# estimator depending on another independent variable

Tags: regression, estimation, linear-model

I think I have a very basic question but I find it a little confusing.
I have a model and I want to derive a regression equation. For example,

$y=\beta x_{1}+ \alpha x_{2} +\epsilon$

The problem is, according to my model $\alpha = \alpha(x_{1})$; the parameter depends on independent variable. For instance, I am regressing the number of excessively consumed coke on each individual's misperception and price. However, the problem is misperception does not only decide the excessive amount but also how the individual responds to a price change.

In that case, would it be enough to add an interaction term as follow?

$y=\beta x_{1}+ \alpha x_{2} + \gamma x_{1} *x_{2}+\epsilon$